# Tokina SZ-X SLR 28-200mm Lens to Nikon D3300

Tags: nikon, pentax, slr, tokina

I'm sure these kinds of questions are asked all the time but is it possible to mount an old SLR lens like this on a newer DLSR camera? The Tokina lens is made for a Pentax K1000 and I have a Nikon D3300. I've also got a Canon FD 70-210mm zoom lens but I read online you can't use those with DSLR bodies. Does anybody know where I could find an adapter for these lenses, if they're even compatible? Any info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Adapting lenses is all about the flange distance. An adapter can make the distance longer but not shorter, unless it has some quality-reducing optics are used which is quite rare and expensive.

The flange distance of the Nikon F-mount is longer than both Pentax K-mount and the Canon one, so there is no adapter that works that way.

Comment: What about something like this? https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/995088-REG/fotodiox_fd_nk_g_pro_nikon_f_adapter.html

Comment: That's an example using optics. Note that it's the equivalent of a 1.4x teleconverter, and like most generic teleconverters, performance can vary significantly depending on the lens/converter pairing. (Matched teleconverters usually do a decent job with the lens(es) they're designed for, but general purpose ones tend to be variable). Contrast that with mechanical-only adapters, which keep the original lens performance. Sadly, Nikon has about the longest flange to sensor/film distance, so you're usually out of luck, but other brands can often use a mechanical-only adapter with Nikon fit lenses.